# Excel VBA - Issue with Worksheet_Change Code

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I'm trying to create a macro that puts the date in a cell on another worksheet, when the initial worksheet is changed, but it gives me an out of range error. Is there any way to get around this, or am I simply unable to use the Worksheet_Change for this case. If so, what can I use? I was simply trying to test it, so I only have this so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Worksheets("Sheet4").Activate
    Range("E1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = Date

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I now have this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Worksheets("Testing Sheet").Range("E2").Value = "" Then
        Worksheets("Testing Sheet").Range("E2").Value = Date
    Else
       ' Worksheets("Testing Sheet").Range("E2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = Date
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

But the statement at the Else is giving me an error saying Application defined or object defined error. (side note I don't have it commented out in my actual code)

Comment: Check the following:  
1) worksheet ("Sheet4") exists? Look for spelling / space on worksheet name  
2) Where are you getting "Date" from?

Comment: @Alex I was able to get to the sheet. The sheet name was different but it was the 4th sheet, so I thought I had to call it "Sheet4" instead of its actual name, but the date prints in "Sheet5" still

Comment: Worksheets("Sheet4") explicitly looks for a worksheet named "Sheet4".  If you intended to activate the 4th Sheet, go Sheets(4).Activate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get error because you are checking condition this

```
If Worksheets("Testing Sheet").Range("E2").Value = "" Then
```

For Suppose you have some value `E2 Cell`. So it goes to `Else` statement

```
Worksheets("Testing Sheet").Range("E2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = Date
```

But probably don't have data below `E2 Cell`. So `.End(xlDown)` Selects `E1048576 Cell` Which is the last allowed row supported by excel.

`.Offset(1, 0).Value` tries to point `E1048577 Cell` which is not supported.

So you get Application Defined Error. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: That makes so much sense. If I have a title in E1 that says "Date", can I just replace the E2 in that line of code with E1 and have it solve the problem? @Jagadish Dabbiru

Comment: You can actually use `Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` to find the last used row.